# How to show status bar icon for the Alarm set

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am developing a little Alarm clock application for my own purposes.
What I want to know is how to tell the system that an alarm is set in order to show the alarm icon on the RIGHT side of the status bar (where battery, signal etc. are).
I found a way to put the time of my next alarm by writing it to system settings, though it might not be a good way. But I can't figure out how to get this icon.
There are posts on this saying it's impossible, but there actually are apps on the PlayStore that do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "there actually are apps on the PlayStore that do it" -- name any.

Comment: @CommonsWare e.g. Puzzle Alarm Clock by Wro Claw Studio, it does show the default icon for a set alarm in the top right corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the Alarm icon in status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23106554/383414) with answers that show how to do it pre-Lollipop

Comment: Also Timely Alarm Clock does this, plus on Lollipop as well