# get rid of AlarmClock icon on status bar for the alarm set using Alarmmanager.AlarmClock()

Tags: android, alarmmanager, statusbar, android-alarms

I have set Alarms using AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(...) method.My alarms were set but, when these alarms were set using it, My device shows AlarmClock icon on top right of the status bar.

[image]

whereas I would not like to show that icon over there and would like that to be disappeared.Is there any remedy that does not show icon on status bar.

Googled related to this issue but neither related to my query nor solution to my issue were found.
Please help me out in this regard.Looking forward for a solution to this.
Hope I conveyed clearly else please let me know. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105038/controlling-the-alarm-icon-in-status-bar

Comment: as far as I got, it says that when an alarm was set the icon was shown and icon get disappears when once the alarm rings.whereas I would like to hide that icon when the alarm was set itself.